# frame pointer register 'ebx' modified by inline assembly code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Unfortunately, I had to re-image my laptop to install Visual Studio 2012. My project build but with above warning. Previously I had Visual Studio 2010 and I never got the above warning. The code is as follows:

```
__asm
{
    //Initialize pointers on matrices
    mov eax, dword ptr [this]

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+UPkk] 
    mov dword ptr [UPkk_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+UPk1k] 
    mov dword ptr [UPk1k_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+DPk1k] 
    mov dword ptr [DPk1k_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+DPkk] 
    mov dword ptr [DPkk_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+mat_A] 
    mov dword ptr [mat_A_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+vec_a] 
    mov dword ptr [vec_a_ptr],ebx

    mov ebx, dword ptr [eax+vec_b] 
    mov dword ptr [vec_b_ptr],ebx
}
```

Do I need to change any settings in the project?

Best Regards

Chintan

Edit: In the above code when I replace ebx with ecx, the warnings go away and the code works fine. However, there is another piece of code where I have used ebx and ecx and in that case my program crashes. Here is the code:

```
__asm
{
    //Initialize UPk1k[idx_4] pointer
    mov eax, dword ptr [UPk1k_ptr]
    mov ebx, dword ptr [idx_4]
    imul ebx,8
    add eax,ebx
    mov dword ptr [UPk1k_id4_ptr],eax

    //Initialize UPkk[idx_4] pointer
    mov eax, dword ptr [UPkk_ptr]
    mov ebx, dword ptr [idx_4]
    imul ebx,8
    add eax,ebx
    mov dword ptr [UPkk_id4_ptr],eax

    //Initialize UPk1k[idx_4] pointer
    mov eax, dword ptr [vec_b_ptr]
    mov ebx, dword ptr [idx_1]
    imul ebx,8
    add eax,ebx
    mov dword ptr [vec_b_id1_ptr],eax

    mov edi, dword ptr [idx_1] //Load idx_1 in edi
    mov esi, 0 //initialize loop counter
    jmp start_proc11

    start_for11:inc esi //idx_2++

    start_proc11:cmp esi, edi //idx_2<idx_1 ?
    jge end_for11 //If yes so end of the loop

    mov eax, UPk1k_id4_ptr //load UPk1k[idx_4] adress
    mov ebx, vec_b_ptr //load vec_b adress
    mov ecx, esi
    imul ecx,8
    add eax, ecx //UPk1k[idx_4+idx_2] in eax
    add ebx, ecx //vec_b[idx_2] in eax

    fld qword ptr [eax]//push UPk1k[idx_4+idx_2]
    fld qword ptr [ebx] //push vec_b[idx_2]
    mov edx,dword ptr [Sd_ptr]
    fmul qword ptr [edx] //vec_b[idx_2]*Sd
    fadd //pop UPk1k[idx_4+idx_2]+vec_b[idx_2]*Sd
    mov edx,dword ptr [UPkk_id4_ptr]
    fstp qword ptr [edx+esi*8] //pop UPkk[idx_4+idx_2]=UPk1k[idx_4+idx_2]+vec_b[idx_2]*Sd
    fld qword ptr [ebx] //push vec_b[idx_2]
    mov edx,dword ptr [vec_b_id1_ptr]
    fld qword ptr [edx] //push vec_b[idx_2]
    fmul qword ptr [eax]
    fadd
    fstp qword ptr [ebx]
    jmp start_for11 //end of the loop
    end_for11:
}
```

Many Thanks

Best Regards

CS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See MSDN [about registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx) and that [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywz8xf2a.aspx). They explain why the warning is produced: it forces the compiler to preserve value of EBX, which might be counter-productive to performance, the usual reason inline asm is used. Relevant quote:

> In addition, by using EBX, ESI or EDI in inline assembly code, you
>   force the compiler to save and restore those registers in the function
>   prologue and epilogue.

To disable the warning, I think the syntax is

[`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx)`( disable : 4731 )`

However, I'd try to use some other register instead, because the warning is there for a good reason, really, like most warnings.

In fact, Looking at your asm code, **simply replace `ebx` With `ecx`, that should solve the problem.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Replacing with `ecx` solvs the problem. Cheers CS

Comment: But now my program crashes :)

Comment: @chintans Well, I would suggest converting the inline asm to plain C++ code, and see if crash disappears (or debug if it does not). Then see what the assembler output looks like (with optimizations enabled), to see if there's any reason what so ever to use inline asm... Also you could compare that assembler output to assembler output of the version which uses inline asm.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is that there is another part of the code where I have used ecx already. Another point is that when I build the project in Debug mode, I do not get these warnings.